# Rotating Image View Continuously in Android

Tags: android

I am using following code to rotate image view

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
<rotate 
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    >
</rotate>
</set>
```

Animation rotate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_picture);
rotate.startAnimation(rotate1);

The Layout which I am using is:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/loader"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:id="@+id/rotate"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But it is stop 500ms and restarting again. But I need to rotate image continuously. Without stopping it in middle. How can I do this?

Comment: What does your layout look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
    //custom_anim.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000" />
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000">
    </alpha>
    <scale
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromXScale=".1"
        android:fromYScale=".1"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="2000" />

</set>


//Oncreate 

 Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);

            imgageview.startAnimation(rotateimage);
            rotateimage.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    AnimateandSlideShow();
                }
            });


//function
private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
Animation rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);

            imgageview.startAnimation(rotateimage);
            rotateimage.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    AnimateandSlideShow();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: After how much time the animation will stop ?.

Comment: increse the duration in android:duration="" tag

Comment: it should be dynamic based server response

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it. For some odd reason it uses the `AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator` as default. Add `android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"` and you will get something more useful.

However there is still a tiny stop after every 500ms, I think it reloads the animation or it has one frame too much (0 = 360)

You can increase the values for a longer duration to get a better effect. Try `android:duration="50000"` and `android:toDegrees="36000"`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in rotate attribute

```
android:repeatMode="restart"
```

Or change your rotate1.xml file, remove set tag. Like this:

```
<rotate 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromDegrees="0"
   android:toDegrees="360"
   android:duration="500"
   android:repeatCount="infinite"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="50%">
</rotate>
```